# Replace function not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
function process2(hours2, mins2, seconds2){
    var system = 2;
    while (system == 2) {
        seconds2--;

        if (seconds2.charAt(0) == "0" || seconds2.charAt(0) == 0) {
            seconds2 = seconds2.replace(/0/i, ""); //Replace functions
        }
        if (mins2.charAt(0) == "0" || mins2.charAt(0) == 0) {
            mins2 = mins2.replace(/0/i, "");
        }
        if (hours2.charAt(0) == "0" || hours2.charAt(0) == 0) {
            hours2 = hours2.replace(/0/i, "");
        }
        document.getElementById("container_fields").innerHTML = "Hours: " +   hours2 + " Minutes:" + mins2 + " Seconds: " + seconds2;}

        setTimeout(function(){
            process2(hours2, mins2, seconds2);
        }, 1000);

}
```

Whenever I open this webpage the program stops and nothing is printed. I am not sure if the problem is with the replace function or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Is `seconds2` a number or a string?  If it's a number, you can't call `seconds2.charAt()`.  If it's a string, you can't do `seconds2--`.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix your syntax problem, you still have a `setTimeout()` "fork bomb" problem.  You're kicking off infinitely many `setTimeout()`s, all of which are set off one second later.  Then, when all those `process2()`s are called, each of them will kick off infinitely many `setTimeout()`s as well.